# Add Java-implemented function into Nashorn's global scope

Tags: nashorn

I'm trying to migrate/update my project to use Nashorn from Rhino. I have some global utility functions implemented in Java and added into global scope of the target script engine, typical example is `log(message)`.

In Rhino it is implemented via

```
public static class LogFunction extends org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction {
    @Override
    public Object call(Context cx, Scriptable scope, Scriptable thisObj, Object[] args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

whose instance added into target scope. What has to be done in case of Nashorn? I can't find how standalone function can be implemented for Nashorn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily implement script functions in Java. You just implement any @FunctionalInterface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) interface using a lambda and expose the same as a global variable by calling ScriptEngine.put (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) method. The following example implements two such script 'functions' implemented in Java code.

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
     ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");

     // expose 'log' function - any @FunctionInterface Java
     // object can be exposed as 'function'
     e.put("log", (Consumer<String>)System.out::println);

     Random r = new Random();
     // expose 'next gaussian' as script global function
     e.put("gaussian", (Supplier<Double>)r::nextGaussian);

     // call functions implemented in Java!
     e.eval("log('hello')");
     e.eval("print(gaussian())");
     e.eval("print(gaussian())");
  }
}
```

Comment: How kotlin do this? If I use kotlin r::nextGaussia as Supplier<Double>. It throw an CastException.

Answer (score 2):

Some time after asking the question I googled once again and found this post: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nashorn-dev/2013-December/002520.html

> *) Implement any @FunctionalInterface interface in JDK (or your own 
>   @FunctionalInterface)  and pass/put object of the same in a 
>   javax.script.Bindings or even global scope. Script can access these as 
>   though these are functions.
>
> *) Implement jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject in your class and 
>   implement "call" method on it. Again, nashorn's flexible dynalink based 
>   linker will treat your JSObject impl. as though it is a function. This 
>   can also be used to implement "constructor" (newObject method) in Java 
>   code and so on.

I decided to go with JSObject implementation and my code looks more Rhino-like and closer to my original code than approach recommended in Sundararajan's answer. Not sure if there any performance difference between them.

```
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.AbstractJSObject;

public static class PrintFunction extends AbstractJSObject {

    public PrintFunction() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFunction() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call(Object thiz, Object... args) {
        ... do something ...

        return null;
    }
}

...

void onInitScriptObjects(Bindings scope) {
    scope.put("print", new PrintFunction());
}
```

Comment: `@FunctionalInterface` approach does not work for me. The simple `Consumer` is OK, but an implementation of a custom interface simply labeled with `@FunctionalInterface` annotation results into a "...is not a function". Sample: https://pastebin.com/jT26hpmp