# How do I track variable dependencies in Nashorn?

Tags: java, nashorn

I would like to use the Nashorn engine as a general computation engine. It is powerful, fast has plenty of built-in functions and new functions are very easy to add, using [@FunctionalInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289217/add-java-implemented-function-into-nashorns-global-scope) or [static methods](https://www.n-k.de/riding-the-nashorn/#_invoking_java_methods_from_javascript). Even better, it also provides value-adds like cyclic dependency checking, syntax checking, etc.

However I need to automatically update "output" variables when a dependency changes.

The general idea is that in Java, I'll have something like:

```
class CalculationEngine {
   Data addData(String name, Number value){
       ...
   }
   Data addData(String name, String formula){
       ...
   }
   String getScript(){
       ...
   }
}

CalculationEngine engine = new CalculationEngine();
Data datum1 = engine.addData("datum1", 1); // Constant integer 1
Data datum2 = engine.addData("datum2", 2); // Constant integer 2
Data datum3 = engine.addData("datum3", "datum1*10");
Data datum4 = engine.addData("datum4", "datum3+datum2");
```

The CalculationEngine service class knows how to use Nashorn to create a script string out of the `Data` objects that looks like this:

```
final String script = engine.getScript(); // "var datum1=1; var datum2=2; var datum3=datum1*10; var datum4=datum3+datum2;"
```

I know I can parse the script with the Nashorn Parser:

```
final CompilationUnitTree tree = parser.parse("test", script, null);
```

But how do I extract the dependencies:

```
List<Data> whatDependsOn(Data input){
   // Process the parsed tree 
   return list;
}
```

such that `whatDependsOn(datum2)` returns [datum4] and `whatDependsOn(datum1)` returns [datum3, datum4] ?

Or the inverse function `getReferencedVariables` such that `getReferencedVariables(datum3)` returns [datum1] and `getReferencedVariables(datum4)` returns [datum2, datum3] (and I can recursively query `getReferencedVariables` until all referenced variables have been found).

Basically, when the "value" of one of my `Data` objects change (due to an external event), how I determine which of my script formulae are affected and need to be recomputed?

I know that the [Nashorn script can be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776811/nashorn-abstract-syntax-tree-traversal) but I can not figure out how to use the `SimpleTreeVisitorES6` to build up a variable dependency graph:

```
    final CompilationUnitTree tree = parser.parse("test", script, null);

    if (tree != null) {
        tree.accept(new SimpleTreeVisitorES6<Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void visitVariable(VariableTree tree, Void v) {
                final Kind kind = tree.getKind();
                System.out.println("Found a variable: " + kind);
                System.out.println(" name: " + kind.toString());
                IdentifierTree binding = (IdentifierTree) tree.getBinding();
                System.out.println(" kind: " + binding.getKind().name());
                System.out.println(" name: " + binding.getName());
                System.out.println(" val: " + kind.name());

                return null;
            }
         }, null);
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to duplicate reactive programming from scratch; maybe it'd make more sense to explore existing options?

Comment: @dave-newton I need to investigate. The primary requirement is to bind external Java classes (represented by Data) and formulae in a calculation engine such that . I do want to reuse an existing framework as much as possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of Nashorn devs here. What you are trying to do is compute the so called def-use relations on source code (well, more likely their transitive closure, but I digress). That's a well-understood compiler theory concept. The good news is that `CompilationUnitTree` and friends should give you enough information to implement an algorithm for computing this information. The bad news is you'll have to roll up your sleeves and roll your own implementation, I'm afraid. You'll basically have to gather this information, produce merges at control flow join points (back edges and exits of loops, ends of if statements, but you'll also have to handle more exotic stuff like switch/case with their fallthrough semantics and also try/catch/finally, which is the least fun of these as basically control can transfer from anywhere in try block to a catch block.) Your algorithm will also have to repeatedly evaluate loop bodies until the static information you're gathering reaches a fixpoint.

FWIW, while writing Nashorn I had to implement these kinds of things few times using Nashorn's internal parser API (which is different but similar to the public one). If you want some inspiration, you can look into the [source code for Nashorn static type analyzer for inferring types of local variables](https://www.javatips.net/api/openjdk-master/nashorn/src/jdk.scripting.nashorn/share/classes/jdk/nashorn/internal/codegen/LocalVariableTypesCalculator.java) in a JavaScript function which is something I wrote some years ago. If nothing else, it'll give you an idea how to walk an AST tree and keep track of control flow edges and partially computed static analysis data at the edges.

I wish there were an easier way to do this… FWIW, a generalized static analyzer that helps you with bookeeping of flow control could be possible. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Fortunately my use-case is greatly simplified by not needing to support flow control. There is a request to support "if", but that is all  (and I think that's a mistake - the ternary operator makes much more sense). Basically I only need a "calculation engine" to manage "result by formula" (transformations, e.g. convert radians to degree) and "validations" (formulae that return a Boolean). But I need to walk the dependency tree when any "input" variable changes (through an external event from the SCADA control system).

Comment: I'm finding a lack of examples of using Nashorn. In particular, when I view the variables in Eclipse (local variables), I can see a "node" element (e.g. viewing the "initialiser" from 'tree.getInitializer();', I can see a "node" element that contains interesting information, in my case "{U%}a + 2". But I can't find which of the BinaryTree public methods return this! I'll check out the 'LocalVariableTypesCalculator' (and related) and look for clues.

Comment: Because of some specifics to the project that I need this for, I am advocating that we perform our own, external, variable dependency tracking. I accept your answer, because it correct for the question that I asked. Thanks!